# Using static function binding in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I have a XAML file, where i want to replace field names with variables so i can have  translation support for more languages for my application.

The way i currently use translation in my application is something like Translation.getString("stringname") (Translation is a static class with static getString function which fetches the translated string from a resource file)

Now for the xaml part I have something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some string for translation" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I can do something like this:

Code:

```
var translatedString = Translation.getString("stringname")
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding translatedString}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

But this is pretty ugly and verbose. Can i somehow access the function directly from xaml?

Such as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{CustomBinding stringname}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Where i somewhere in my project assign that using "CustomBinding bla" will run it as a function Translation.getString("bla") and uses the returned string for my desired translation effect.

Is this possible somehow?

Is there some other "business standard" in which this is usually done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by creating custom **`MarkupExtension`** and use that in place of Binding.

```
public class TranslateString : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
            return Value;
        return Translation.getString(Value);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it from XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:TranslateString Value='Some string for translation'}"/>
```

Ofcourse you have to define namespace **`local`** at root level like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Replace `WpfApplication1` with actual namespace of class TranslateString.

Answer (score 1):

That I know about, there is no business standard for this kind of problem.

If there's anything true about XAML, it's that it's verbose. That's not always a bad thing but it means that even controls with simple custom behaviors can be tricky.

There is a [recommended workflow for globalizing an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621(v=vs.110).aspx), but it is complex, and I kid you not, actually includes instructions to use and modify a microsoft-supplied sample application as part of the workflow.

Another alternative is to develop as you normally do, and [use a tool like Sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com/) to broker the localization. Naturally, this is easier but it costs come money.

Using either workflow, you could define your strings in `Application.Resources` and reference them as a `DynamicResource`.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    Dictionary<string, string> localizer;

    public App()
    {
        localizer = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "loc", "locdsasdasd" } };
        //LoadLocalizer(); 
        this.Resources.Add("Localizer", localizer);
    }
}
```

**LocBinding.cs**

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
public class LocBinding : Binding
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> localizer=((Dictionary<string,string>)   
     (App.Current.Resources["Localizer"]));

    public LocBinding(string property)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("binding path is null");

        string value;
        if (localizer.TryGetValue(property, out value))
            this.Source = value;
        else
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(property + "key is not defined in       
            localizer");
    }
}
}
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{local:LocBinding loc}"/>
</Grid>
```

this one value in localizer is just for testing .But in real these values will be filled from database or xml or .resx file.

Comment: I combined both this and the accepted answer and it works exactly the way i want, perfect.